# como fazer um arquivo principal js chamar funcões de outros arquivos js no servidor sem usar framework

Tags: javascript, express.js, back-end

vou explicar.
tenho um arquivo main no meu servidor que é rodado pelo npm start
esse arquivo main chama outro arquivo resposavel pelas rotas "Routes"
o probelma ´que o routes esta abarrotado de codigo nas rotas então eu quero chamar um arquivo diferente para rodar em cada rota deixando meu arquivo Routes com menos responsabilidate

main: "index.js"

```
 const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const cors = require('cors');
const boryparser = require('body-parser');


const tt = require('./gatopreto');



const routes = require('./routes')
//const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var porta = process.env.PORT || 8877;

const app = express();
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(boryparser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(routes);


app.listen(porta,()=>{
    console.log('rodando na porta: '+porta);
})
```

Route "routes.js"

```
    const { json, text } = require('body-parser');
       const express = require('express');
       const routes = express.Router();

routes.get('/api/teste',(req,res)=>{

//vou chamar a function 


 let a = ent('deu?')
   console.log(a); 
    
    return res.send('rota funcionando')
})
module.exports = routes;
```

aquivo que quero chamar "gatopreto.js":

```
function ent(input){
    return input+' saida';
}
```

**ERRO RETORNADO**

```
ReferenceError: ent is not defined
```

Comment: pronto acabei de colocar o codigo de exemplo

Comment: Faça um export no outro .js e chame esse outro .js no seu main/index JS principal usando require. Exemplo https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/what-is-require/

Comment: não conseguin da uma olhando como eu tô tentando fazer {atualizei os codigos acima}

Comment: No gatopreto.js faça o exports conforme o exemplo do link que citei acima. Aqui (MDN) segue um link mais detalhado: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export. Bons estudos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma maneira de resolver o problema é configurando as funções que deseja através da função `export`.

Supondo a seguinte estrutura de pastas:

```
projeto
│   app.js
│
└───server
│   │   index.js
│   │
│   │
│   └───routes
│       │   login.route.js
│       │   ...
│   
└───services
    │   login.service.js
    |   ...
```

Desta forma desejamos utilizar os `middlewares` definidos dentro da pasta `services` nos arquivos de rotas estes arquivos estão contidos no diretório `routes` e após serem definidos eles são importados no arquivo `server.js` que posteriormente é importado no arquivo `app.js`.

Esse seria uma descrição do que desejamos fazer, a forma concreta do que desejamos implementar seria:

***app.js***

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.use(require('./server/index'));

module.exports = app;
```

***server/index.js***

```
const router = require('express').Router();

router.use(require('./routes/login.route.js'));

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json({msg: "server up and running"});
});
  //após tentar casar todas as rotas a ultima rota que sobrou é not found
router.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.status(404).json({ errors: [{location: req.path, msg: 'Not found', param: null}]});
});

module.exports = router;
```

***server/routes/login.route.js***

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const loginService = require('../controllers/login.controller');

router.post('/login', loginService.hashPassword, loginService.lookupLogin, loginService.logEmployee);

module.exports = router;
```

***server/services/login.service.js***

```
const postgres = require('../../lib/postgres');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const crypto = require('crypto');

exports.logEmployee = (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json({ token: 'Bearer ' + jwt.sign(req.employee, process.env.SECRET, { expiresIn: 1800 }) });//expires in 1800 seconds
    res.end();
};

exports.hashPassword = (req, res, next) => {
    crypto.scrypt(req.body.password.toString(), 'salt', 256, (err, derivedKey) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({ errors: [{ location: req.path, msg: 'Could not do login', param: req.params.id }] });
        }
        req.body.kdfResult = derivedKey.toString('hex');
        next();
    });
};

exports.lookupLogin = (req, res, next) => {
    const sql = 'SELECT e.employee_id, e.login FROM employee e WHERE e.login=$1 AND e.password = $2';
    postgres.query(sql, [req.body.login, req.body.kdfResult], (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({ errors: [{ location: req.path, msg: 'Could not do login', param: req.params.id }] });
        }
        if (result.rows.length === 0) {
            return res.status(404).json({ errors: [{ location: req.path, msg: 'User or password does not match', param: req.params.id }] });
        }
        req.employee = result.rows[0];
        next();
    });
};
```

Essa seria uma organização de pastas sugerida. A maneira de exportar uma função é utilizando a sintaxe do comando exports do `nodejs`. Você pode aprender mais sobre o [exports](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export).

Estou utilizando funções exportadas no formato middleware, e sempre quando desejo chamar o próximo item dos middlewares chamo a função `next()`. Saiba mais sobre [express middlewares](https://expressjs.com/pt-br/guide/using-middleware.html)